# Rain Water is considered pure or impure

Tags: rituals, customs

Normally when it rains after a homa, yagna or any religious activity, it is considered auspicious ("devatas are pleased with the ritual; hence its raining"). However, while performing Kumbabhishekam (consecration) of temple, if the rain water falls directly on the vigraha (idol), it is customary that a a fresh kumbabhisheka need to be performed.

Above are based on customs and may vary from place to place. Related to above, I have two questions:
a) Why rain is considered auspicious but rain water is not in some cases?

b) What is purity of rain water for direct use in rituals (direct use = capture rain water and use it directly in the rituals; rain water hasn't joined river, lake, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

> 2 He becomes pure by sipping water collected on the ground,* 3 or when
> a pure person gives him water to sip. 4 **He should not sip rain
> water** 5 or water in a crevice, 6 as also warm water without a good
> reason
>
> *Apasthambha Dharma Sutras 1.15.2-6*

Therefore, it is clear that for the purpose of purification (e.g. bath or Achamana) rain water must be avoided as impure.

Comment: thanks. Interesting! Any reason why rain water is not suitable for rituals, or why if rain water falls on idols, its need fresh kumbabhisheka...

Comment: Not sure why but the verse clearly says not to do achaman using rain water .. so rain water is impure ..if it falls on idols for purifying the idols Abhisekha must be needed @Kanthri